# Dealing with activity parameters with duplicate names in Brightway2

Tags: brightway

Brightway2 allows [parameterization](https://2.docs.brightwaylca.org/intro.html#parameterized-datasets) at the activity level. These activity-level parameters need to be added to a group via 
 `new_activity_parameters` or `add_to_group`. 
I'm struggling finding the best approach for dealing with the case where (1) calculations need to be done with activity-parameters from multiple activities and (2) parameters from the different activities can have the same parameter name (i.e. we may find "fuel_efficiency" in many activities).

```py
act_params_data_A = {
    'name': 'fuel_efficiency',
    'database': 'db',
    'code': 'A',
    'amount': 0.5
}
act_params_data_B = {
    'name': 'fuel_efficiency',
    'database': 'db',
    'code': 'B',
    'amount': 0.9
}
```

Here are some options, and why they either straight-out don't work, why they seem sub-optimal or what I'm missing to make them work. I'm looking for some guidance.

**Option 1: Add both activity parameters to the same group, overwrite=False (does *NOT* work)**

```py
parameters.new_activity_parameters(act_params_A, "some_group")
parameters.new_activity_parameters(act_params_B, "some_group", overwrite=False) #--> raises ValueError
```

**Option 2: Add both activity parameters to the same group, overwrite=True (does *NOT* work)**

```py
parameters.new_activity_parameters(act_params_A, "some_group")
parameters.new_activity_parameters(act_params_B, "some_group", overwrite=True)
```

This overwrites `act_params_A`, so activity A will use 0.9 as value for the `fuel_efficiency`.

**Option 3: Modify activity parameter names to make them unique, and then add to the same group**

```py
act_params_data_A['name'] = "{}_{}".format(
    act_params_data_A['code'],
    act_params_data_A['name']
) # New name is A_fuel_efficiency

act_params_data_B['name'] = "{}_{}".format(
    act_params_data_B['code'],
    act_params_data_B['name']
) # New name is B_fuel_efficiency
parameters.new_activity_parameters(act_params_A, "some_group")
parameters.new_activity_parameters(act_params_B, "some_group")
```

This would work, and the uniqueness of names is guaranteed since the uniqueness of codes is guaranteed. *However*, there is no guarantee that the codes are acceptable strings for parameter names (e.g. an activity can have a key=('db', 'some code'), and 'some code_fuel_efficiency`is not a valid parameter name). We could of course "clean" the activity code, but this *could* result in non-unique cleaned parameters.

**Option 4: Each activity is sent to its own group**

```py
parameters.new_activity_parameters(act_params_A, "some_group")
parameters.new_activity_parameters(act_params_B, "other_group")
```

The problem is that I'm unsure how to then **use** these groups, especially how to pass these to a presamples `ParameterizedBrightwayModel`. We can of course create a super group, and make these activity-level groups dependencies, but dependencies (where the first encounter of a parameter name from a defined group order) and name-spaces (activity parameters exist within activities) are different things so I'm not sure if that would even help.

---

Have I missed anything?